# Mongodb doc object has undefined properties (via Mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am working on an app that should send a notification to an android device. But problem is that I can't get deviceToken from MongoDB. When I `console.log(doc)` it is an object.

```
 { _id: 584f1762022f3b17bac48e75,
 clientPhoneNumber: '1',
 cost: 35,
 __v: 0,
 createdAt: 2016-12-12T21:32:18.824Z,
 clientDeviceToken: 'APA91bEtcIxVkrOKm-ypm0fYjrFFuqki--MD_1xvOcpMZf0QWPyBYaqRDVZJDs',
 taken: true,
 end:
  { district: 'Râșcani',
   address: 'Studenților 9/7',
 latitude: 47.061752,
 longitude: 28.867122 },
start:
 { district: 'Râșcani',
 address: 'Nicolae Dimo 1111',
 latitude: 478,
 longitude: 28 } }
```

But when i reffer to a property `doc.clientDeviceToken` it is undefined

There is my code:

```
router.post('/newTakenOrder', (req, res) => {
let takenOrder = req.body
let newTakenOrder = TakenOrder(takenOrder)

newTakenOrder.save((err, doc) => {
if (err) {
  res.json(err)
} else {
  Order.update(
    { _id: takenOrder.orderId },
    { $set: {taken: true} },
    (err, numAffected) => {
      if (err) res.json(err)
      console.log(numAffected)
  })
  Order.find(
    { _id: takenOrder.orderId },
    (err, doc) => {
      if (err) {
        res.json(err)
      } else {
        regTokens.push(doc.clientDeviceToken)
        message.addNotification('title', `Your Order was taken. Driver time to arrive ${takenOrder.timeToArrive}`)
        sender.send(message, { registrationTokens: regTokens }, function (err, response) {
            if (err) res.json(err)
            else {
//                  console.log(response)
              console.log('token doc => ' + Object.keys(doc))
  //                console.log(`apiKey --> ${config.gcmApiKey}`)
    //              console.log(`taken ==> ${regTokens}`)
            }
        })
        message = new gcm.Message()
        regTokens = []
      }
    }
  )
  res.send({message: 'TakenOrder created'})
}
  })
})
```

Comment: can you tell when are you saving `clientDeviceToken` in the document,and how exactly.

Comment: I solved this problem. To access a property from Mongoose doc you must write `doc[0].toObject(). clientDeviceToken` instead of `doc.clientDeviceToken`

Comment: Yes, `find` returns an `array` of documents, but not object, Thats why you need to do `doc[0].clientDeviceToken` . if you were using `findOne`, that returns an object, in that case you can use `doc.clientDeviceToken`.

Comment: you can directly use `doc[0].clientDeviceToken` instead of `doc[0].toObject().clientDeviceToken`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDb findOne result property is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68056844/mongodb-findone-result-property-is-undefined)