# MongoDb findOne result property is undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, nestjs

I am using a findOne in a model and it returns a response.

```
    const findAccount = await this.accountModel.findOne({
        _id: ObjectId(param.accountId),
    });
     
    console.log(findAccount);
    //The above logs the data
    console.log(findAccount.role, findAccount._id);
    //As for this, findAccount.role is undefined, but the findAccount._id was logged.
```

What could be the cause?

Comment: Can you show your model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findOne` method returns an instance of Mongoose document, which can lead to situations like this. To get the Javascript plain object, you can use [`lean()` method](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html). Try this:

```
    const findAccount = await this.accountModel.findOne({
        _id: ObjectId(param.accountId),
    }).lean();
     
    console.log(findAccount);
    //The above logs the data
    console.log(findAccount.role, findAccount._id);
```